# What DependencyInjection container can be used in .NET 2.0?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection

I usually use StructureMap in v 2.5.  I think that v2.0 ist compatible to .NET 2.0 but I dont feel comfortable using an older version.

Are ther any other more recent containers that support .NET 2.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [Spring.NET](http://www.springframework.net/). The latest version still supports .NET 2.0 (actually .NET 1.x too) according to the documentation.